# How can I generate json specification file dynamically with open api in Angular?

Tags: angular, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have used Swgger ui like below code and now I want to create pet.json dynamically

```
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    SwaggerUI({
        domNode: document.getElementById('swagger-ui-item'),
        url: 'assets/pet.json'
      });
}
```

I have a list of APIs and when one of the APIs is selected, I want to display the Swagger page for that API only.
[image]

Comment: Can you give some more details what to want to achieve? Swagger UI is a web-based tool that reads a Swagger/OpenAPI specification and dynamically generates an interactive documentation website that allows users to explore the API's endpoints, parameters, and responses.

Comment: I have a list of APIs and when one of the APIs is selected, I want to display the Swagger page for that API only.

Comment: 1) Does that API already have an OpenAPI definition listing all endpoints and you just want to filter it to display just some of the endpoints? Or do you currently have no OpenAPI definition for that API and you need to generate it from code? 2) How is that "list of APIs" implemented? Does your screenshot show an app that you written, or is it some 3rd-party app/product? The more details, the easier it would be for others to suggest solutions.

Comment: Full information of APIs is defined by users in the system, APIs are in different projects

Comment: I don't currently have any definition of APIs and I want to open api them through code in angular

Answer (score 0):

The url should point to an api definition like this: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json, or in case you host this one also in the angular app in assets, you could refer locally also.

check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swagger-ui-integration?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts